# Get current script file

Tags: powershell

Within a PS script, how can I retrieve an object that represents or points to the script file? Something like get-currentscript.

What I really want to do is retrieve the script file creation and/or modification time. Presumably this would be retrievable from the script file object. Of course, I could also use a dumb old file spec for the current script file.

Comment: $PSCommandPath will return the path (including filename) to the currently executing script.

Answer (score 9):

Check out this answer on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/817198/how-can-i-get-the-current-powershell-executing-file):

While the current answer is correct in most cases, there are certain situations that it will not give you the correct answer. If you use functions inside your script then:

```
$MyInvocation.MyCommand.Name
```

returns the name of the function instead name of the name of the script.

```
function test {
    $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Name
}
```

Will give you "test" no matter the script name. The right command for getting the script name is always

```
$MyInvocation.ScriptName
```

This returns the full path of the executing script. If only the script filename is wanted then use this:

```
Split-Path $MyInvocation.PSCommandPath -Leaf
```