# How would I start the same script I am running in Powershell again after a restart?

Tags: powershell, automation

The location of the script when searching for it references the Scheduled task and sometimes references PowerShell any possible idea to get it to reference the script.

Path of script auto_test.ps1.

```
C:\Scripts\auto_test.ps1
```

This is the actual script.

```
param(
    #File 1 used for update
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [string]$file1='',

    #File 2 used for update
    [string]$file2='',

    #File 3 used for update
    [string]$file3=''

)
Start-Process $file1 -ArgumentList "AC=1 ON=1"
if ( (-not [String]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($file2)) -and [String]::IsNullorWhiteSpace($file3))
{
    $taskTrigger = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -AtStartup 
    $taskName = "Update"
    $taskAction = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute 'powershell.exe' -Argument ($PSCommandPath + " -file1 $file2")
    # Describe the scheduled task.
    $description = "Automation Testing"

# Register the scheduled task
Register-ScheduledTask -TaskName $taskName -Action $taskAction -Trigger $taskTrigger -Description $description
shutdown -r
}
if ( [String]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($file2))
{
Unregister-ScheduledTask -Taskname "Update"
shutdown -r
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get current script file](https://superuser.com/questions/1259169/get-current-script-file)

Comment: @Destroy666 Does it return the full path because if the computer restarts it won't remember the full path to the script is an assumption I am making.

Comment: did you read that entire answer? If so, not sure where the question is coming from.

Comment: I am going to add the path to the script.

Comment: @Destroy666 It references the path of the scheduled task and not the path of the script that I am using. Is there any way to get it to reference the path of the script. I even tried $MyInvocation.Command.Path.